# Explanation for the proof of Minkowski's inequality, Theorem 3.5, Rudin's RCA

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, proof-explanation, integral-inequality

I understand how can we get the second factors on the right of $(10)$ from the second factors on the right of $(9)$. But I don't know how can we get the first factor on the right of $(10)$, i.e., $$\big\{\int(f+g)^p\big\}^{1/q}.$$
I think he omitted some step here. It probably has another inequality between $(9)$ and $(10)$.
[image]
*

- I omitted the proof for $(1)$.

*
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

He explains it:$$\left\{\int(f+g)^{(p-1)q}\right\}^{1/q}=\left\{\int(f+g)^p\right\}^{1/q},$$since $(p-1)q=p$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int(f+g)^{p}&=\int f\cdot(f+g)^{p-1}+g\cdot(f+g)^{p-1}\\
&\leq\left\{\int f^{p}\right\}^{1/p}\left\{\int(f+g)^{(p-1)q}\right\}^{1/q}+\left\{\int g^{p}\right\}^{1/p}\left\{\int(f+g)^{(p-1)q}\right\}^{1/q}\\
&=\left\{\int(f+g)^{p}\right\}^{1/q}\left[\left\{\int f^{p}\right\}^{1/p}+\left\{\int g^{p}\right\}^{1/p}\right].
\end{align*}